# How to get distance from object to spatial mapping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm working with Unity 2017.4, the HoloToolKit 2017.4.3, Vuforia and the Hololens.
How can I calculate the distance of a virtual object to the spatial mapping of the Hololens? I only need the distance in the Z coordinate, like in "how many meters above the floor is my object".

Comment: Please add any supporting code or information about anything you've already tried.

Comment: the spatial mapping is providing generated mesh on runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As u didnt provide much information, here my first idea. Raycast from the object down to ground/ceiling and take the distance.

```
     RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
     if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit)) {
         var distanceToGround = hit.distance;
     }
```

Comment: I just realized that the spatial mapping is just a mesh in Unity and nothing special. Thank you!